# Open_basedir in wordpress images are not uploading

Tags: wordpress, open-basedir

I install wordpress 3.8 on cpanel linux server.but enable to uplaod images due error open_basedir in effect.how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `open_basedir` setting prevents users (=PHP processes) from browsing the file system. It does this by limiting PHP's access to the user's home directory, /tmp, and a few necessary PHP system directories.

In cPanel you can find your open_basedir settings at Home>Security Center>PHP>"open_basedir Tweak".

This security tweak modifies the Apache configuration file of your server directly, regardless of the PHP handler currently selected. If PHP is configured to run as a CGI, suPHP, or FastCGI process, you must manually specify the open_basedir directive in the appropriate php.ini file. You can find more information about thie [here](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/TweakPhp).

Please try use proper spelling in the future and provide more details (for example how you tried to fix it). That will make it a lot easier to provide proper answers.